# Path обрезает часть изображения если линии выходят за область рисования

Tags: wpf, path

Квадрат рисуется со сторонами одинаковой толщины:

```
<Path Data="M0,0 L100,0 L100,100 L0,100 Z"
      StrokeThickness="20"
      Stroke="Black"
      Width="200"
      Height="200" />
```

[image: фигура 1]

Квадрат рисуется со сторонами разной толщины (фигура обрезается):

```
<Path Data="M0,0 L100,0 L100,100 L0,100 Z L200,200"
      StrokeThickness="20"
      Stroke="Black"
      Width="200"
      Height="200" />
```

[image: фигура 2]

1. Почему происходит обрезание фигуры только если она вылазит за пределы области?
2. Как задать, чтобы `Path` не обрезал фигуру независимо от того, вылазит фигура за пределы области рисования или нет? (универсальное решение для любой фигуры)
3. Как задать координату левой верхней точки, например, -20,-20?

Answer (score 2):

Разметку подравняете сами, а так выглядеть должно так

```
<StackPanel Margin="20">
    <Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="20">
        <Path.Data>
            <PathGeometry Figures="M0,0 L100,0 L100,100 L0,100 Z L200,200" />
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
</StackPanel>
```

Где М 0,0 - это и есть начальная точка

Comment: O_o Казалось бы, все то же самое, а работает уже по другому. Почему так?

Comment: А как создать PathGeometry в code behind? Что-то типа такого: new PathGeometry(new PathFigure { Data = str });

Comment: Vitaliy, что типа такого PathGeometry myPathGeometry = new PathGeometry();
myPathGeometry.Figures = myPathFigureCollection;

Comment: Нашел такое решение: myPathGeometry.Figures = PathFigureCollection.Parse(value);

Comment: Это не является ответом на вопрос, потому что были убраны размеры Width="200" и Height="200". Если их убрать - фигура никогда не обрезается, но её размер меняется при изменении фигуры. Мне же нужно зафиксировать размер `Path`, но при этом, чтобы фигура никогда не обрезалась. Сейчас она обрезается если фигура вылазит за область рисования справа или внизу и не обрезается, если вылазит слева или сверху (странное поведение).

Comment: Vitaliy там есть параметр M 0,0 это и есть координата начальной точки, если вы её измените, то вся фигура по плывет,тогда надо будет менять все параметры.